# C# Is clearing a List<T> with value types still an O(n) operation?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list

According to the Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), calling Clear() on a List is an O(n) operation. I'm guessing this is because if the list were to hold references, it would need to null them. I was wondering if Clear() is still an O(n) operation if the list has value types, since the capacity is not changed. Shouldn't it be enough to reset the index pointer and count?

I'm asking this because in a current application we're using lists that get cleared hundreds of thousands of times in a very short time span, and wanted to know if there could be a different implementation that makes it faster.

Comment: A value type could contain a reference that the user would expect to be gone after calling `Clear`. You've got to overwrite or reallocate the entire underlying array in the general case.

Comment: what about just calling new List<T> and letting GC handle removing the content from memory? Possibly you could implement an extension that handles overwriting and size of the "new" (not new but overwritten content) list meaning that you never delete.

Comment: List may not be the datatype for you.

Comment: You can always implement your own `List<T>` equivalent on top of arrays. A bit of boilerplate, but shouldn't take very long.

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian That's still `O(n)` when it eventually happens. It's not like the GC doesn't need to sweep up the memory range occupied by the list's backing array.

Comment: @OP Why do you need to clear these lists so regularly? Can't you just overwrite the content and truncate? The truncation overhead there is still worst case `O(n)` but it's probably much better in average case.

Comment: @Asad As you said, the content is really overwritten in our use case. Truncating would still be slower than just resetting the count and index, no? I was asking to know if I'd have to make my own List implementation to better fit my needs. MikeZ's explanation made me understand why List<T> must always remove its contents, thanks.

Comment: @Hans What is your use case for the list? Do you only need to iterate through the items one way? If so, it would be much cheaper to have an IEnumerable or linked list.

Comment: @Asad I'm doing a depth first tree search, and instead of having a parent reference on the node objects, they store a list with the actions that preceded them; these actions being represented by ints. The node objects are pooled, so when they get disposed I needed to clear the list of actions. Then when the children are created for a node, the parent's list is copied to the children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspecting in List.Clear method source code:

```
Array.Clear(_items, 0, _size);
_size = 0;
```

Array.Clear is an extern method
and MSDN statement about [Array.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is:

> Sets a range of elements in an array to the default value of each element type.

So it is still an O(n) operation even if T is a value type.